# Is it possible to make a Google Wallet Pass shareable via their API

Tags: google-wallet

As of 2023 Google Wallet allows users to share a pass. This is apparently up to the issuer to enable but I'm unable to find any information on the Google Wallet API documentation about how to enable the sharing feature.

[Example of share on Pass](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQvZQ.png)

My question to you is, how can I enable the sharing on passes, such as the generic pass type.

- Looked through Google Wallet API documentation.
- Enabled multiple holders via `multipleDevicesAndHoldersAllowedStatus`

Answer (score 1):

If you omit the `multipleDevicesAndHoldersAllowedStatus` key, you will enable shareability of the Google Wallet Pass by default.